# JPA connection : is this code is efficient enough

Tags: java, design-patterns, hibernate, jpa

By reading some tutorial i have written some peace of code to do crud operation . I just want to know how is this code is efficient or how can i make better ?

Here i am giving code of 3 class 
 1. EntityManagerProvider  : get connection from DB and do crud operation
 2. BaseDao : A generalised Dao which uses EntityManagerProvider
 3. TargetGroupsDao  : A specific Dao

```
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.persistence.EntityExistsException;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceException;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.persistence.RollbackException;
import javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException;

public class EntityManagerProvider {

    private static EntityManagerFactory emf;
    private static boolean lock;
    private static String persistentUnitName = "TMS_PU";
    static {
        EntityManagerProvider.emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persistentUnitName);
    }
    private static final ThreadLocal<EntityManager> localEm = new ThreadLocal<EntityManager>() {
        @Override
        protected EntityManager initialValue() {
            if (emf == null || !emf.isOpen()) {
                emf = Persistence
                        .createEntityManagerFactory(persistentUnitName);
            }
            return emf.createEntityManager();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        if (em != null && em.isOpen())
            em.close();
        super.finalize();
    }

    public EntityManagerProvider() {
    }

    public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        EntityManager em = localEm.get();
        if (em == null || !em.isOpen()) {
            em = emf.createEntityManager();
            localEm.set(em);
        }
        return em;
    }

    public static void beginTransaction() {
        if (lock)
            return;
        EntityTransaction tx = getEntityManager().getTransaction();
        if (!tx.isActive()) {
            tx.begin();
        }
    }

    public static void rollbackTransaction() {
        EntityTransaction tx = getEntityManager().getTransaction();
        if (tx != null && tx.isActive()) {
            tx.setRollbackOnly();
        }
    }

    public static void commitTransaction() {
        if (lock)
            return;
        EntityTransaction tx = getEntityManager().getTransaction();
        if (tx != null && tx.isActive()) {
            try {
                if (tx.getRollbackOnly())
                    tx.rollback();
                else
                    tx.commit();
            } catch (RollbackException e) {
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }

    public void persist(Object object) throws Exception {
        try {
            if (object instanceof Collection) {
                Collection<?> objects = (Collection<?>) object;
                for (Object o : objects) {
                    getEntityManager().persist(o);
                }
            } else {
                getEntityManager().persist(object);
            }
        } catch (EntityExistsException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (TransactionRequiredException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            rollbackTransaction();
            throw e;
        } finally {
        }
    }

    public Object merge(Object object) throws Exception {
        Object result = null;
        try {
            if (object instanceof Collection) {
                Collection<?> objects = (Collection<?>) object;
                for (Object o : objects) {
                    getEntityManager().merge(o);
                }
            } else {
                result = getEntityManager().merge(object);
            }
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (TransactionRequiredException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            rollbackTransaction();
            throw e;
        } finally {
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void clear() throws Exception {
        try {
            getEntityManager().clear();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public void flush() throws Exception {
        try {
            getEntityManager().flush();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (TransactionRequiredException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (PersistenceException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }

    }

    public Object getById(final Class<?> persistentClass, Object id) {
        return getEntityManager().find(persistentClass, id);
    }

    public Object getReferenceById(final Class<?> persistentClass, Object id) {
        return getEntityManager().getReference(persistentClass, id);
    }

    public void remove(Object valueObject) throws Exception {
        try {
            EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
            em.remove(valueObject);
            em.flush();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (TransactionRequiredException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            rollbackTransaction();
            throw e;
        } finally {
        }
    }

    public Query createQuery(String jpql) {
        return getEntityManager().createQuery(jpql);
    }

    public static void lock() {
        lock = true;
    }

    public static void unlock() {
        lock = false;
    }

    public static boolean getlock() {
        return lock;
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.persistence.Query;
public class BaseDao {
    private EntityManagerProvider emp;
    private Class<?> className;

    public BaseDao(final Class<?> className) {
        this.className = className;
        emp = new EntityManagerProvider();

    }

    public BaseDao(final Class<?> className, String localMsg) {
        this.className = className;
        emp = new EntityManagerProvider();
    }

    public void create(Object object, EntityManagerProvider emp)
            throws Exception {

        try {
            if (emp == null) {
                EntityManagerProvider.beginTransaction();
                this.emp.persist(object);
                EntityManagerProvider.commitTransaction();
            } else {
                emp.persist(object);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }

    }

    public void update(Object object, EntityManagerProvider emp)
            throws Exception {

        try {
            if (emp == null) {
                EntityManagerProvider.beginTransaction();
                this.emp.merge(object);
                EntityManagerProvider.commitTransaction();
            } else {
                object = emp.merge(object);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }

    }

    public Object getById(Object primaryKey) throws Exception {

        Object object = null;
        try {
            emp = new EntityManagerProvider();

            // FLUSH
            EntityManagerProvider.beginTransaction();
            // emp.flush();
            // emp.clear();

            object = emp.getById(className, primaryKey);
            EntityManagerProvider.commitTransaction();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return object;
    }



    public Object getReferenceById(Object primaryKey) throws Exception {
        Object object = null;
        try {
            emp = new EntityManagerProvider();
            object = emp.getReferenceById(className, primaryKey);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return object;
    }

    public List<?> getAll() throws Exception {
        return getAll(null, null);
    }

    public List<?> getAll(Integer fromRowNo, Integer noOfRows) throws Exception {

        List<?> list = null;
        String sql = null;
        Query query = null;
        try {
            emp = new EntityManagerProvider();
            // CLEAR & FLUSH
            EntityManagerProvider.beginTransaction();
            emp.flush();
            emp.clear();
            EntityManagerProvider.commitTransaction();

            sql = "SELECT p " + "FROM " + className.getCanonicalName() + " p";
            query = emp.createQuery(sql);

            if (fromRowNo != null)
                query.setFirstResult(fromRowNo);
            if (noOfRows != null)
                query.setMaxResults(noOfRows);

            list = query.getResultList();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return list;
    }

    public void delete(Object primaryKey, EntityManagerProvider emp)
            throws Exception {
        Object object = getById(primaryKey);
        if (object == null) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            if (emp == null) {
                EntityManagerProvider.beginTransaction();
                this.emp.remove(object);
                EntityManagerProvider.commitTransaction();
            } else {
                emp.remove(object);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public List<?> search(Map<String, Object> var, String opr) throws Exception {
        return search(var, null, null, true, null, null, opr);
    }

    public List<?> search(Map<String, Object> var, Integer fromRowNo,
            Integer noOfRows, String opr) throws Exception {
        return search(var, null, null, true, fromRowNo, noOfRows, opr);
    }

    public List<?> search(Map<String, Object> var, Map<String, Boolean> flags,
            String opr) throws Exception {
        return search(var, flags, null, true, null, null, opr);
    }

    public List<?> search(Map<String, Object> var, Map<String, Boolean> flags,
            Integer fromRowNo, Integer noOfRows, String opr) throws Exception {
        return search(var, flags, null, true, fromRowNo, noOfRows, opr);
    }

    public List<?> search(Map<String, Object> var, Map<String, Boolean> flags,
            Map<String, Boolean> orderBy, Boolean orderFlag, Integer fromRowNo,
            Integer noOfRows, String opr) throws Exception {
        List<?> list = null;

        if (opr == null)
            opr = "AND ";

        try {
            emp = new EntityManagerProvider();
            String sql = "SELECT p FROM " + className.getCanonicalName()
                    + " p ";
            String sql2 = null;
            String sql3 = null;
            String str2 = null;

            if (var != null) {
                for (String str : var.keySet()) {
                    if (str.indexOf(".") > 0) // This solves only for one
                        // level
                        str2 = str
                                .substring(str.indexOf(".") + 1, str.length());
                    else
                        str2 = str;
                    if (sql2 != null) {
                        if (flags != null) {
                            if (!flags.get(str))
                                sql2 += opr + "p." + str + " != :" + str2 + " ";
                            else
                                sql2 += opr + "p." + str + " = :" + str2 + " ";
                        } else
                            sql2 += opr + "p." + str + " = :" + str2 + " ";
                    } else {
                        if (flags != null) {
                            if (!flags.get(str))
                                sql2 = "WHERE p." + str + " != :" + str2 + " ";
                            else
                                sql2 = "WHERE p." + str + " = :" + str2 + " ";
                        } else
                            sql2 = "WHERE p." + str + " = :" + str2 + " ";
                    }
                }
            }

            if (orderBy != null) {
                for (String str : orderBy.keySet()) {
                    if (sql3 != null) {
                        if (orderBy.get(str) != null && orderBy.get(str))
                            sql3 += ", p." + str + " ";
                    } else {
                        if (orderBy.get(str) != null && orderBy.get(str))
                            sql3 = " ORDER BY p." + str;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (sql2 != null)
                sql += sql2;

            if (sql3 != null) {
                if (orderFlag)
                    sql += sql3;
                else
                    sql += sql3 + " DESC ";
            }

            Query query = emp.createQuery(sql);

            for (String str : var.keySet()) {
                if (str.indexOf(".") > 0) // This solves only for one level
                    str2 = str.substring(str.indexOf(".") + 1, str.length());
                else
                    str2 = str;
                query.setParameter(str2, var.get(str));
            }

            if (fromRowNo != null) {
                query.setFirstResult(fromRowNo);
            }
            if (noOfRows != null) {
                query.setMaxResults(noOfRows);
            }

            EntityManagerProvider.beginTransaction();
            // emp.flush();
            // emp.clear();
            list = query.getResultList();
            EntityManagerProvider.commitTransaction();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }

        return list;
    }

    public Integer countRecords(Map<String, Object> var,
            Map<String, Boolean> flags, String opr) throws Exception {
        Long count = null;

        if (opr == null)
            opr = "AND ";

        try {
            emp = new EntityManagerProvider();
            String sql = "SELECT COUNT(p) FROM " + className.getCanonicalName()
                    + " p ";
            String sql2 = null;
            String str2 = null;

            if (var != null) {
                for (String str : var.keySet()) {
                    if (str.indexOf(".") > 0) // This solves only for one
                        // level
                        str2 = str
                                .substring(str.indexOf(".") + 1, str.length());
                    else
                        str2 = str;
                    if (sql2 != null) {
                        if (flags != null) {
                            if (!flags.get(str))
                                sql2 += opr + "p." + str + " != :" + str2 + " ";
                            else
                                sql2 += opr + "p." + str + " = :" + str2 + " ";
                        } else
                            sql2 += opr + "p." + str + " = :" + str2 + " ";
                    } else {
                        if (flags != null) {
                            if (!flags.get(str))
                                sql2 = "WHERE p." + str + " != :" + str2 + " ";
                            else
                                sql2 = "WHERE p." + str + " = :" + str2 + " ";
                        } else
                            sql2 = "WHERE p." + str + " = :" + str2 + " ";
                    }
                }
            }

            if (sql2 != null)
                sql += sql2;

            Query query = emp.createQuery(sql);

            for (String str : var.keySet()) {
                if (str.indexOf(".") > 0) // This solves only for one level
                    str2 = str.substring(str.indexOf(".") + 1, str.length());
                else
                    str2 = str;
                query.setParameter(str2, var.get(str));
            }

            EntityManagerProvider.beginTransaction();
            // emp.flush();
            // emp.clear();
            count = (Long) query.getSingleResult();
//          System.out.println(count); //TODO: REMOVE ME
            EntityManagerProvider.commitTransaction();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }

        return count.intValue();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class TargetGroupsDao {

    private BaseDao baseDao;

    public TargetGroupsDao() {
        baseDao = new BaseDao(TargetGroupsDo.class, TargetGroupsDao.class.getName());
    }

    public void create(TargetGroupsDo targetGroupsDo, EntityManagerProvider emp) throws Exception {
        baseDao.create(targetGroupsDo, emp);
    }

    public void update(TargetGroupsDo targetGroupsDo, EntityManagerProvider emp) throws Exception { 
        baseDao.update(targetGroupsDo, emp);
    }

    public TargetGroupsDo getById(String serialId) throws Exception {
        return (TargetGroupsDo)baseDao.getById(serialId);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<TargetGroupsDo> getAll(Integer fromRowNo, Integer noOfRows) throws Exception {
        return  (List<TargetGroupsDo>)baseDao.getAll(fromRowNo, noOfRows);
    }

    public void delete(String serialId, EntityManagerProvider emp) throws Exception {
        baseDao.delete(serialId, emp);
     }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<TargetGroupsDo> search(TargetGroupsDto targetGroupsDto, Integer fromRowNo, Integer noOfRows, String opr) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        if( targetGroupsDto.getTgDesc()!= null && !targetGroupsDto.getTgDesc().trim().equals(""))
            map.put("tgDesc", targetGroupsDto.getTgDesc());
        if( targetGroupsDto.getTgId()!= null && !targetGroupsDto.getTgId().trim().equals(""))
            map.put("tgId", targetGroupsDto.getTgId());
        if( targetGroupsDto.getTgName()!= null && !targetGroupsDto.getTgName().trim().equals(""))
            map.put("tgName", targetGroupsDto.getTgName());
        if( targetGroupsDto.getOwnershipType()!= null && !targetGroupsDto.getOwnershipType().trim().equals(""))
            map.put("ownershipType", targetGroupsDto.getOwnershipType());
        if( targetGroupsDto.getNoOfMembers()!= null)
            map.put("noOfMembers", targetGroupsDto.getNoOfMembers());
        return (List<TargetGroupsDo>)baseDao.search(map, fromRowNo, noOfRows, opr);
    }

    public TargetGroupsDo getReferenceById(String tgId) throws Exception {
        return (TargetGroupsDo)baseDao.getReferenceById(tgId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1.This sample is really ugly :) You can extract method `isEmptyTrim()` at least.

```
if( targetGroupsDto.getTgDesc()!= null && !targetGroupsDto.getTgDesc().trim().equals(""))
    map.put("tgDesc", targetGroupsDto.getTgDesc());
if( targetGroupsDto.getTgId()!= null && !targetGroupsDto.getTgId().trim().equals(""))
    map.put("tgId", targetGroupsDto.getTgId());
if( targetGroupsDto.getTgName()!= null && !targetGroupsDto.getTgName().trim().equals(""))
    map.put("tgName", targetGroupsDto.getTgName());
if( targetGroupsDto.getOwnershipType()!= null && !targetGroupsDto.getOwnershipType().trim().equals(""))
    map.put("ownershipType", targetGroupsDto.getOwnershipType());
if( targetGroupsDto.getNoOfMembers()!= null)
    map.put("noOfMembers", targetGroupsDto.getNoOfMembers());
```

2.Cycle over keyset is a bad practice.

```
 for (String str : var.keySet()) {
```

You should use

```
 for (Entry<String, Object> entry : var.entrySet()) {
```

Comment: Any Comment on Connection setting ? 
And The way BaseDao is used within TargetGroupsDao is correct?

Comment: @codesparkle Why? If you need both key and value, then entrySet() should be used. The link that you posted says exactly the same, too.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't precise enough: in one case, only the key is used; there, `keySet()` is the right choice. All others should indeed be `entrySet()`.